# Using Phonegap NFC Plugin in Ionic to scan RFID tags

Tags: ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, capacitor

I am using Phonegap Plugin in ionic for scanning RFID tags and tried creating a build for IOS.
I am using nfc.scanNdef() function as described here https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc for IOS. The code looks like this:

```
  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        let tag = await this.nfc.scanNdef();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tag));
     } catch (err) {
         console.log('Error reading tag ngoninit', err);
     }
  }
```

The issue is that the scanning session starts on my iPhone but it does not scan the tag at all. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Using IOS version 15.5
Device iphone 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scanTag instead of using scanNdef and try it again. Please see https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).